# Express $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i(i+j)}$ in terms of harmonic numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, harmonic-numbers

> Express $$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i(i+j)}$$ in terms of the harmonic numbers $H_n$.

I guess that there could be several approaches for doing this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $S$ be the desired sum.  By interchanging the roles of $i$ and $j$, we have $$2S=\sum_i \sum_j \left( \frac{1}{i(i+j)}+\frac{1}{j(i+j)} \right) = \sum_i \sum_j \frac{1}{ij} =H_n^2.$$ Hence $S=H_n^2/2$.

Comment: it will be better to write the answer as$\frac{1}{2}(H_n)^2..$

Answer (score 4):

$\begin{array}\\
S
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i(i+j)}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac1{j}(\frac1{i}-\frac1{i+j})\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac1{j}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (\frac1{i}-\frac1{i+j})\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac1{j}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac1{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac1{i+j}\right)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac1{j}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac1{i}-\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac1{j}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac1{i+j}\\
&=H_n^2-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac1{j}\frac1{i+j}\\
&=H_n^2-S\\
\text{so}\\
S
&=\frac12 H_n^2\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: @ it will be better to write the answer as $\frac{1}{2}(H_n)^2..$

Comment: You say either and I say potato.